# Validate avro files in java

Tags: apache, avro

Is there any API to validate a avro file?To make sure that file is not corrupt.

Currently i am using DataFileWriter.getSchema() to check if the avro is not corrupt. But only checking schemna doesnt ensure that file is not corrupt.

I am left with option of reading every record. Is there any other way to validate the avro file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no other way.  Avro [files](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Object+Container+Files) can be thought of as a delimited file with a header.  The header specifies both the fields and their types, and the records are just binary delimited data.  Just as text delimited data, the only way to be 100% sure is to check every record.